# Using Mouse scroll plus Control for iWork suite?

Tags: macos, catalina, pages, keynote, iwork

I would like to use zoom function in *Pages / Keynote* using Mouse scroll + Control while I work most of the time using an external monitor without trackpad.

Such feature works in .pdf viewer or Affinity designer, which I use on regular basis.

Is there any way to adjust such zooming for the iWork Apps?

Comment: You could configure Accessibility to enable zooming across macOS. Open System Preferences > Accessiblity > Zoom and select "Use scroll gesture with modifier keys to zoom". See https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-accessibility-features-mh35884/mac for details.

Comment: @jaume Thanks, I knew this feature, however, it sets zooming in/out the whole screen. What I would like to achieve, is to zoom the page in any iWork App (mostly Pages) using "Mouse scroll + Control ^" button - zoom in/ou can be performed by trackpad, but when I use external monitor I don't have any and so it gets frustrating.